# Sqlite atomic operations

Tags: c#, sqlite

I run 5 applications which are using the same `sqlite` database (each application is different process). Unfortunately operations like `GetEmptyPort` have to be atomic to prevent returning same values. Right now I achieve that by using system `Mutex`, but I dont like  this solution. Is there any built-in solution to do this in pure `sqlite`?

This is my code:

```
private static Mutex DB_MUTEX = new Mutex(false, "FOO_DB_MUTEX");

private T OnMutexWork<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try
    {
        DB_MUTEX.WaitOne();
        return func.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        DB_MUTEX.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

private SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    return new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
}

private int GetEmptyPort(int min, int max)
{
    return OnMutexWork<int>(() =>
    {
        using (var conn = GetConnection())
        {
            var allPorts = conn.Table<Port>()
                    .ToList();

            for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            {
                if (!allPorts.Any(x => x.Value == i))
                {
                    var item = new Port() { Value = i};
                    conn.Insert(item);
                    return i;
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("Couldn't find empty port");
        }
    });
}
```

I tried what @Shawn Suggested:

```
private int GetEmptyPort(int min, int max)
{
    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
        conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
            var allPorts = conn.Table<Port>()
                .ToList();

            for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            {
                if (!allPorts.Any(x => x.Value == i))
                {
                    var item = new Port() { Value = i};
                    conn.Insert(item);
                    return i;
                }
            }
        });

        throw new Exception("Couldn't find empty port");
    }
}
```

But I am getting `SQLite.SQLiteException: 'Busy'` error when accessing database from different connections.

Comment: Please add a more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: Exclusive transactions. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen which part you don't understand?

Comment: @Shawn can you look at my tries with transaction? I edited above post